# Expected ProductField, got array issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

I have a rails 4 application that has a params block that looks like:

```
def store_params
   params.require(:store).permit(:name, :description, :user_id, products_attributes: [:id, :type, { productFields: [:type, :content ] } ])
end
```

but I'm getting the error:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in StoresController#create
ProductField expected, got Array
```

The parameters I'm trying to insert look like:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "store"=>{"name"=>"fdsaf", "description"=>"sdfd","products_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"productFields"=>{"type"=>"", "content"=>""}}}}, "type"=>"Magazine", "commit"=>"Create store"}
```

My models are

1. Store (has a `has_many :products`)
2. Product (has a `has_many :productFields` and `belongs_to :store`)
3. ProductField (has a `belongs_to :product`)

My view looks like:

```
<%= f.fields_for :products do |builder| %>
  <%= render 'product_fields', f: builder %>
<% end %>
```

and then the product_fields partial:

```
<%= f.fields_for :productFields do |builder| %>
  <%= builder.text_field :type%>
  <%= builder.text_area :content %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I mean the `code`.And also post the view `code` of your `form_for`

Comment: Do you set `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in the models?

Comment: @Pavan, I actually just realized I forgot to put `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in the ProductField model (I already had one in the Product model). But when I put this, the inputs that `<%= builder.text_field :type%>
 <%= builder.text_area :content %>` generate, disappear?

Comment: ok.I will post my answer.

Comment: Ok, that'd be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure your Product and Store models have:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for
```

inside them.

Then, if your calling nested fields_for like that, make sure you build them (in the controller), something like:

```
product = @store.products.build
product.productFields.build
```

Answer (score 4):

Firstly you should have set `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in your models like this

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_fields
  belongs_to :store
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_fields
end

class ProductField < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :products
end
```

Secondly, your `store_params` should look like this

```
def store_params
  params.require(:store).permit(:name, :description, :user_id, products_attributes: [:id, :type, { product_fields_attributes: [:type, :content ] } ])
end
```