# Create associated records when creating a user with Devise taking an attribute for the associated record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have a user model and through the model membership, it has many organizations:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :organizations, through: :memberships
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :organization
end

class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, through: :memberships
end
```

During the signup process, I want to ask for the name of my organization, so, my form looks like this:

```
= simple_for_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f|
  = devise_error_messages!
  = f.simple_fields_for :memberships do |fm|
    = fm.input :kind, as: :hidden, input_html: {value: Membership::OWNER}
    = fm.simple_fields_for :organization do |fo|
      = fo.input :name, required: false, label: "Organization"
  = f.input :name
  = f.input :email
  = f.input :password
  = f.input :password_confirmation
```

and my custom strong params definition in my custom Devise registration controller looks like this:

```
def configure_sign_up_params
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) do |u|
    u.permit(:email, 
             :password, 
             :password_confirmation, 
             memberships: {organizations: [:name]})
  end
end
```

When I submit the form, I get this error:

```
Membership(#70355446274100) expected, got Array(#70355394078720)
```

on Devise's create controller action. The parameters look like this:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"...",
 "user"=>
   {"memberships"=>
     {"kind"=>"owner",
      "organizations"=>{"name"=>"Organization name"}},
   "name"=>"User's Name",
   "email"=>"email@address.com",
   "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
   "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"},
 "commit"=>"Sign up"}
```

If I add

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :memberships 
accepts_nested_attributes_for :organizations
```

to the user model or if I add:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :memberships
```

to the user model and

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :organizations
```

to the membership model, the membership and organization simple disappear for the form, they are not rendered. Even when my new registration controller action looks like this:

```
def new
  super
  resource.memberships.build.build_organization
end
```

I also tried defining my strong params as this:

```
def configure_sign_up_params
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) do |u|
    u.permit(:email,
             :password,
             :password_confirmation,
             memberships_attributes: [:id, organization_attributess: [:id, :name]])
  end
end
```

and it (obviously) made no difference in the HTML input field not appearing.

What am I missing? How can I make this work?

In regards to this question being a duplicate of [Expected ProductField, got array issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23571220/expected-productfield-got-array-issue) , nowhere in that question or answers is the matter of forms addressed, which I am addressing here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expected ProductField, got array issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23571220/expected-productfield-got-array-issue)

Comment: @Pavan In regards to this question being a duplicate of Expected ProductField, got array issue , nowhere in that question or answers is the matter of forms addressed, which I am addressing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you made several mistakes in all kind of places. Please replace your code with my correction below (so not to miss singular/plural cases). Unfortunately, I can't really test my code, but I think it is pretty close to what your need.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :organizations, through: :memberships

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :memberships
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :organization

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :organization
end

class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, through: :memberships
end


= simple_for_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f|
  = devise_error_messages!
  = f.simple_fields_for :memberships do |fm|
    = fm.input :kind, as: :hidden, input_html: {value: Membership::OWNER}
    = fm.simple_fields_for :organization do |fo|
      = fo.input :name, required: false, label: "Organization"
  = f.input :name
  = f.input :email
  = f.input :password
  = f.input :password_confirmation


def configure_sign_up_params
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) do |u|
    u.permit(:email, 
             :password, 
             :password_confirmation, 
             memberships_attributes: [:id, organization_attributes: [:id, :name]])
  end
end
```

Here is how I would handle your view (instead of building your resouces in the new action). You can remove your buildings in that new action and try this view:

```
= simple_for_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f|
  = devise_error_messages!
  = f.object.memberships.build if f.object.memberships.empty?
  = f.simple_fields_for :memberships do |fm|
    = fm.input :kind, as: :hidden, input_html: {value: Membership::OWNER}
    = fm.object.build_organization unless fm.object.organization
    = fm.simple_fields_for :organization do |fo|
      = fo.input :name, required: false, label: "Organization"
  = f.input :name
  = f.input :email
  = f.input :password
  = f.input :password_confirmation
```

Comment: Thank you @gen. I actually played a lot with it and I tried this exact solution (minutes _attributes in the strong params). I made my code look exactly like what you specify here and the organization name field just doesn't appear. Even when I add    resource.memberships.build.build_organization to the new action, there's no input field in the html.

Comment: I think the problem relates to resource.membership being empty when creating the form. I don't think the form will automagically decide to add one and only one membership.

Comment: @Pablo: Well, I can't check what you tried, but I just added another way to write your view. While it uses the logic to build things inside the view, I find it as a better way to handle complex associations.

Comment: @Pablo: Also, if I recall correctly, to build resources with Devise your need to override `build_resource` method. The view design that I use should not require this.

Comment: @Pablo: Have you tried my changes for the view? Of course "strong params" will not affect your HTML, I just added corrections for them in order to avoid your future issues after form submit.

Comment: Yes, I tried your current version and there are these two problems (potentially related): it tries to save a membership without setting the user and organization so validation fails. It doesn't seem to try to save the organization and when the form comes back, the value for organization.name is lost.

Comment: @Pablo: It is much better. Ooops, I made a copy-paste error. Correct to this: `= fm.object.build_organization unless fm.object.organization`. We are close. We can move to discussions if you have further issues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116937/discussion-between-pablo-and-gen).